# Recents Screen and Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-recents

What is the exact life-cycle path for an Android activity when it is shown to the user in the recents screen and when it renters into the user's view? I want to know if I can determine if the user left the app (onPause() and/or onStop()) is called and then returned back to it with the activity remaining in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  Is the activity still resident in memory or was it destroyed?  In the first case, it would get onStart, then onResume.  In the second, it would go through the entire normal lifecycle of any activity being launched (including onRestoreInstanceState to restore any saved values).

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is to see if the user left the app with the activity still in focus and then came back (didn't destroy the app). I want to know how I can determine the difference between that action and the user leaving the activity for another activity within the app.

Comment: Right, but wouldn't the first activity call onPause() when that happens and then onResume() when the user navigates back (clicking the back button).

Answer (score 0):

Recents screen does not show your activity, it shows only its screenshot. When your app re-enters into the user view (when you sekect from recents), it depends. In most cases, app is not killed, so sequence is `onRestart` ->`onStart`->`onResume`. If app is killed or phone restarted, `onCreate`->`onStart`->`onResume`

Look here: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle